Relative path in helmfile leads to Renovate file-access-violation-error
Having a helmfile.yaml with few releases:
releases:
  - name: task-service
    chart: ../tasks/helm/tasks
    namespace: {{ .Namespace }}
    values:
    - image:
        pullPolicy: Always

  - name: storage
    chart: harbor/storage
    version: 2.0.0

and I want to configure Renovate to renew storage version if available (from Harbor).
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "rebaseWhen": "behind-base-branch",
  "prConcurrentLimit": 10,
  "prHourlyLimit": 100,
  "commitBody": "Changelog: Storage dep",
  "automergeStrategy": "merge-commit",
  "hostRules": [],
  "baseBranches": [
    "main"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "major",
        "minor"
      ],
      "automerge": false,
      "autoApprove": false
    }
  ],
  "regexManagers": [
    {
      "fileMatch": [
        "(^|/)helmfile\\.ya?ml$"
      ],
      "matchStrings": [
        "name\\s?:\\s?storage\\n\\s+chart\\s?:\\s+harbor\\/(?<depName>\\S*)\\n\\s+version\\s?:\\s+(?<currentValue>\\S*)"
      ],
      "datasourceTemplate": "helm"
    }
  ]
}

but when I run it, Renovate fails with error:
DEBUG: Preventing access to file outside allowed directory (repository=local)
       "path": "/Users/my.name/IdeaProjects/tasks/helm/tasks/kustomization.yaml",
       "allowedDir": "/Users/my.name/IdeaProjects/data-catalog-saas-helmfile"
ERROR: Repository has unknown error (repository=local)
       "err": {
         "message": "file-access-violation-error",
         "stack": "Error: file-access-violation-error\n    at assertBaseDir (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/util/fs/util.ts:12:11)\n    at ensurePath (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/util/fs/util.ts:21:3)\n    at ensureLocalPath (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/util/fs/util.ts:26:10)\n    at localPathExists (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/util/fs/index.ts:118:31)\n    at localChartHasKustomizationsYaml (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/modules/manager/helmfile/utils.ts:27:25)\n    at Object.extractPackageFile (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/modules/manager/helmfile/extract.ts:75:49)\n    at extractPackageFile (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/modules/manager/index.ts:75:9)\n    at getManagerPackageFiles (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/extract/manager-files.ts:58:43)\n    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/extract/index.ts:57:28\n    at async Promise.all (index 2)\n    at extractAllDependencies (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/extract/index.ts:54:26)\n    at extract (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/process/extract-update.ts:140:28)\n    at extractDependencies (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/process/index.ts:154:26)\n    at Object.renovateRepository (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/index.ts:69:9)\n    at attributes.repository (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/global/index.ts:218:11)\n    at start (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/global/index.ts:203:7)\n    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/renovate.ts:18:22"
       }
DEBUG: Repository result: unknown-error, status: onboarded, enabled: true, onboarded: true 

and I have no idea why and how to prevent it. The interersting part for me is
"path": "/Users/my.name/IdeaProjects/tasks/helm/tasks/kustomization.yaml"

which leads me that it's something with a relative path chart: ../tasks/helm/tasks in my helmfile.yaml. I tried to find a solution in doc, Google it, I also tried to find some renovate files which I can copy, but no luck.

Reported (and accepted) as a bug: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues/29814
